# Write a decorator for a Python dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-decorators, python-dataclasses

I have the following dataclass:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Info:
    client_id: str
    purchase_id: str
```

Both these ids are supposed to be UUID's.

I have a method that can check if the arg is UUID:

```
from uuid import UUID 

def check_uuid(arg):
    try:
        UUID(arg)
    except ValueError:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"'{arg}' is not a valid UUID")
    return arg
```

I want to define a decorator that I can wrap around my dataclass to perform this check. Something like this:

```
@check_types
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Info:
    client_id: str
    purchase_id: str
```

Here is what I wrote:

```
from functools import wraps

import argparse
import inspect


def check_types(callable):

    def check_uuid(*args, **kwargs):
        for arg in args[1:]
            try:
                UUID(arg)
            except ValueError:
                raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"'{arg}' is not a valid UUID")

    def decorate(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            check_uuid(*args, **kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    if inspect.isclass(callable):
        callable.__init__ = decorate(callable.__init__)
        return callable

    return decorate(callable)
```

but when I instantiate the class `i = Info("123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000", "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000")`

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

I am not sure what I am missing, alternatively, is there a better way I can be type checking for UUIDs when the class is instantiated?

Comment: You are not decorating `__init__`, but the class (already decorated by `dataclass`

Comment: you really should just use something like `pydantic`.

Comment: As an aside, `raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(` is a really strange error to use in this context, and `if inspect.isclass(callable)` can just be `if isinstance(callable, type)`, and you should probably not use `callable` as a parameter name since it shadows the built-in function `callable`

Answer (score 2):

If they are supposed to be UUIDs, then type them as such. The caller should be responsible for parsing any strings *before* instantiating `Info`.

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Info:
    client_id: UUID
    purchase_id: UUID

x = "..."
y = "..."

i = Info(UUID(x), UUID(y))
```

You can help the caller by providing a class method that does the type conversion

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Info:
    client_id: UUID
    purchase_id: UUID

    @classmethod
    def from_strings(cls, x, y):
        # Let any ValueErrors speak for themselves
        x = UUID(x)  
        y = UUID(y)
        return cls(UUID(x), UUID(y))
        

x = "..."
y = "..."
i = Info.from_strings(x, y)
```

Answer (score 2):

A viable decorator would be like this (assuming that all the arguments must be UUIDs):

```
def typecheckedclass(original_class):
    orig_init = original_class.__init__
    def __init__(self, *args, **kws):
        for arg in args:
            try:
                UUID(arg)
            except:
                raise ValueError(f"'{arg}' is not a valid UUID")
        orig_init(self, *args, **kws)
    original_class.__init__ = __init__
    return original_class
```

I catch all the exceptions because catching only `ValueError` ignores other type of conversion errors. For example if an `int` is passed as an argument an `AttributeError` is raised.